# Similarity in Elasticsearch properties in Springframework

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I need to use property "similarity" in my elasticsearch index, but cannot find the property in the Field annotation of Springframework. It seems, the Springframework Elasticsearch library don't have that. Do I need to use another library or are there simple ways to do that? Can you recommend a library or a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Setting](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/Setting.java) annotation and define your settings in a separate file, with the appropriate configuration for similarity.

To perform this, just add `@Setting(settingPath = "/path/to/settings.json")` to your index class, where you have `@Document` annotation.

e.g.

```
@Setting(settingPath = "/path/to/settings.json")
@Document(indexName = "indexName")
public class IndexClass {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And your `settings.json` should look like :

```
"index": {
  "similarity": {
    "my_similarity": {
      "type": "DFR",
      "basic_model": "g",
      "after_effect": "l",
      "normalization": "h2",
      "normalization.h2.c": "3.0"
    }
  }
}
```

And you can find more in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html).

Comment: Thanks. But I mean a annotation for a field. For example,

` @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "some_analyzer", **similarity = "my_similarity"**)
 private String address;`


 But I found out that there is 4.0.0.M3 version with that.

Comment: You're right, I did'nt check next releases. You can fill it with the [Similarity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4.0.0.M3/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/Similarity.java) enum.

Comment: I need the **scripted_tfidf** type of similarity, but I don't figure out it - seems, the [Similarity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/4.0.0.M3/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/Similarity.java) enum don't have the case... Can you give me an advice or point me to the type?

Comment: Yes, a scripted similarities are not "default" ones, and you should implement it in the settings. The `scripted_tfidf ` is taken as example is the doc, so you can add it to your settings following my answer, and use it in your field with what you mentionned : `@Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "some_analyzer", similarity = "scripted_tfidf ") private String address;`.

Comment: But similarity in @Field using as the Similarity enum type and not string in 4.0.0 version, and there are not similarity in earlier versions at all. Maybe I should use the mapping in a json file?

Comment: You're right, in that case, you have to define it in a json file and you can use the `@Mapping` annotation. You can try to use it at field level.